# Necessary Condition for Existence of Functional Extrema

Tags: functional-analysis, calculus-of-variations

> If $J$ is a differentiable functional and has an extremum at $y_{0}$, it must be that its differential is 0. That is, $\delta J[y_{0};h] = 0$ for all admissible $h$.

We go by contradiction. Suppose for some $h_{0}$ that $\delta J[y_{0};h_{0}] \neq 0$. By definition we have that 
$$\lim_{||h||\to 0} \frac{\Delta J[y_{0};h] - \delta J[y_{0};h]}{||h||} = 0 .$$
So for $\varepsilon > 0$ we have for some $0 < \eta < \varepsilon$ that if $||h||<\eta$ then 
$$ \delta J[y_{0};h] - \varepsilon||h|| < \Delta J[y_{0};h] < \delta J[y_{0};h] + \varepsilon||h|| .$$
Let $\alpha > 0$ be small enough so that $||\alpha h_{0}|| < \eta$. Put $g = \alpha h_{0}$. We arrive at the inequalities
\begin{align}
\delta J[y_{0},g] - \varepsilon||g|| &< \Delta J[y_{0},g] < \delta J[y_{0},g]+\varepsilon||g|| \\
-\delta J[y_{0},g] - \varepsilon||g|| &< \Delta J[y_{0},-g] < -\delta J[y_{0},g]+\varepsilon||g||.
\end{align}
We see it cannot be that $\delta J[y_{0},g] \geq \varepsilon||g||$.

I can't bring this home and I'm not sure my "translation" of their definition of differentiable is correct.

Comment: What do $\Delta$ and $\delta$ do?

Comment: $Delta J [y;h] $ is just notation for $J [y+h]-J [h] $ and $\delta J $ denotes the unique linear functional such that the limit abobe is 0.

Comment: (1) Where have you used that $y_0$ is a max/min? (2) You should use the linearity of $\delta J[y_0,\cdot]$.

Comment: I used (2) to arrive at the final inequalities and (1) with those to show the final claim that $\delta J [y_{0}, g]  < \varepsilon||g||$. I am in bed now so I will try it tomorrow, but I am guessing maybe split the proof to the case where it is a max and the case where it is a min and hopefully we reach a contradiction?

Comment: Do you know the usual proof showing that the derivative of a differentiable function is 0 at every max/min? You could try to adapt it here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $J$ is a differentiable functional and has an extremum at $y_{0}$, it must be that its differential is 0. That is, $\delta J[y_{0};h] = 0$ for all $h$.

By definition we have that 
$$\lim_{||h||\to 0} \frac{\Delta J[y_{0};h] - \delta J[y_{0};h]}{||h||} = 0 .$$
So for $\varepsilon > 0$ we have for some $0 < \eta < \varepsilon$ that if $||h||<\eta$ then 
\begin{align*}
\delta J[y_{0};h] - \varepsilon||h|| < \Delta J[y_{0};h] < \delta J[y_{0};h] + \varepsilon||h|| \\
-\delta J[y_{0};h] - \varepsilon||h|| < \Delta J[y_{0};-h] < -\delta J[y_{0};h] + \varepsilon||h||
\end{align*}
Because $J$ is extremized at $y_{0}$, we can also make $\eta$ small enough so that $\Delta J[y_{0};h]$ is either always positive or always negative for all $||h|| < \eta$.  In this case, we see it must be that $|\delta J[y_{0};h]| < \varepsilon||h||$ because otherwise $\Delta J[y_{0};h]$ and $\Delta J[y_{0};-h]$ have opposite signs. But then
$$\frac{|\delta J[y_{0};h]
}{||h||} < \varepsilon  $$
and we see that
$$\lim_{||h||\to 0}\frac{\delta J[y_{0};h]}{||h||} = 0 .$$
The following lemma shows it must be that $\delta J[y_{0};h]$ is identically 0.

> If $J$ is a linear functional such that
>   $$\lim_{||h||\to0}\frac{J[h]}{||h||} = 0 $$
>   then $J$ is identically 0.

Suppose for some $h_{0}$ that $\phi[h_{0}] \neq 0$. Put
$$h_{n} = \frac{h_{0}}{n} \neq 0.$$
As $h_{0}$ must be bounded, we see that $\lim_{n\to\infty}||h_{n}|| = 0$ and
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\phi[h_{n}]}{||h_{n}||} = 0$$
by hypothesis. On the other hand,
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{\phi[h_{n}]}{||h_{n}||} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n\phi[h_{0}]}{n||h_{0}||} = \frac{\phi[h_{0}]}{||h_{0}||} \neq 0 $$
a contradiction.

Comment: From where did you derive the delta is always positive or negative if $||h|| \leq \eta$???

Answer (score -1):

Say, $y$ is a local minimum of $J$. Then there exist $\epsilon > 0$ and a function $R$, defined on the $\epsilon$-ball $B_\epsilon$ around zero, such that for each $h\in B_\epsilon$ you have
$$
0\le J[y+h] - J[y] = \delta J[y,h] + R[h],
$$
where $|R[h]|/\|h\|\to 0$ as $h\to 0$. This also holds for $-h$ instead of $h$, so also $-\delta J[y,h] + R[-h]\ge 0$. This gives
$$
-|R[h]|\le-R[h]\le\delta J[y,h]\le R[-h]\le |R[-h]|
$$
for all $h\in B_\epsilon$. In particular, $|\delta J[y,h]|\le\max\{|R[h]|,|R[-h]|\}$.

Now, fix some $h_0$ with $\|h_0\|=1$. Then for $\alpha\in (0,\epsilon)$ you have
$$
|\alpha||\delta J[y,h_0]| = |\delta J[y,\alpha h_0]|\,\le\,\max\{|R[\alpha h_0]|,|R[-\alpha h_0]|\},
$$
and hence (as $|\alpha| = \|\alpha h_0\| = \|-\alpha h_0\|$),
$$
|\delta J[y,h_0]|\,\le\,\max\left\{\frac{|R[\alpha h_0]|}{\|\alpha h_0\|},\frac{|R[-\alpha h_0]|}{\|-\alpha h_0\|}\right\}.
$$
This holds for any $\alpha\in(0,\epsilon)$. Letting $\alpha\to 0$ yields $\delta J[y,h_0] = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your proof, I managed to solve it (I believe) in a slightly different way before I saw your post. I have posted it here if you'd like to review. One question if you have time, in Gelfand and Fomin's book they claim that if $||h||$ is small enough that $\delta J$ and $\Delta J$ have the same sign (if $y$ extremizes). They assert this without justification and use it in their proof to arrive at a contradiction with linearity. Is it true?